# How to submit to AppStore excluding my Watch app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm still working on my Watch app, and its not ready for submission to the AppStore. My iOS app is. I dont want to delete my watch app extension from my project. Is there another way to submit the iOS app only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just remove the WatchKit extension from your target dependencies and from "Embed App Extensions" in your Build Phases.

Edit for further explanation: When you click on your project in the project navigator, several sections appear such as "General", "Capabilities" etc. Click on "Build Phases". There you will find "Target Dependencies" and "Embed App Extensions".

Comment: Mind explaining how to do this? Thanks.